# SQL Script Not Joining Results

Tags: sql

I am having an issue getting this SQL Script to join the two tables together, I can execute it and it will show the results of the first portion (AccountID, AuditDate ..etc) but it will not join to the inner select statement.

I have verified by spot checking that there is data that matches in the database.

What portion did i mess up?

```
Select AccountID, AuditDate, SourceVersion
From Audit
Left join (
    Select A.PrinterAuditID, A.AuditID, A.SerialNr, A.PageCountTotal,a.PageCountColor, A.PageCountMono
    from  InvalidPrinterAudit A
    where A.DeviceID = 90757
) InvalidPrinterAudit on InvalidPrinterAudit.AuditID = Audit.AuditID
```

Comment: Try this,
Select Audit.AccountID, Audit.AuditDate, Audit.SourceVersion,  A.PrinterAuditID, A.AuditID, A.SerialNr, A.PageCountTotal,A.PageCountColor, A.PageCountMono FROM Audit as Audit LEFT JOIN InvalidPrinterAudit as A on (A.InvalidPrinterAudit = Audit.AuditID) where A.DeviceID = 90757

Comment: Does the inner query return anything? Shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yes the Inner Select will return Data, 

Thank you RAM!!! you got it to work, I had to modify a column name but it works now

Comment: This is the final code that worked for me thank you @Ram


Select Audit.AccountID, Audit.AuditDate, Audit.SourceVersion, A.PrinterAuditID, A.AuditID, A.SerialNr, A.PageCountTotal,A.PageCountColor, A.PageCountMono 
FROM Audit as Audit LEFT JOIN InvalidPrinterAudit as A on (A.AuditID = Audit.AuditID) where A.DeviceID = 90757

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of things happening here.

**One**: In order to have fields in your result set, they must be included in the `SELECT` portion of your query:

```
Select AccountID, AuditDate, SourceVersion, InvalidPrinterAudit.PrinterAuditID, InvalidPrinterAudit.AuditID, InvalidPrinterAudit.SerialNr, InvalidPrinterAudit.PageCountTotal,InvalidPrinterAudit.PageCountColor, InvalidPrinterAudit.PageCountMono
    From Audit
    Left join (
        Select A.PrinterAuditID, A.AuditID, A.SerialNr, A.PageCountTotal,a.PageCountColor, A.PageCountMono
        from  InvalidPrinterAudit A
        where A.DeviceID = 90757
    ) InvalidPrinterAudit on InvalidPrinterAudit.AuditID = Audit.AuditID
```

**Two**: You don't need to have a subquery here. Subqueries are great if you need to aggregate the results from a seperate table or something, but here you can just go with a LEFT OUTER JOIN and be done with it.

```
Select AccountID, AuditDate, SourceVersion, InvalidPrinterAudit.PrinterAuditID, InvalidPrinterAudit.AuditID, InvalidPrinterAudit.SerialNr, InvalidPrinterAudit.PageCountTotal,InvalidPrinterAudit.PageCountColor, InvalidPrinterAudit.PageCountMono
    From Audit
    Left OUTER JOIN InvalidPrinterAudit 
        ON InvalidPrinterAudit.AuditID = Audit.AuditID 
           AND InvalidPrinterAudit.DeviceID = 90757
```

This will apply that `DeviceID = 90757` filter to your `InvalidPrinterAudit` before the join is applied, so you'll still get all of your `Audit` records, and then only the `InvalidPrinterAudit` records for that DeviceID that matches.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting less columns in the outer query than in the inner query.

If you want them to be returned in the resultset, include them in the outer:

```
Select AccountID, AuditDate, SourceVersion, PrinterAuditID, SerialNr
From Audit
Left join (
    Select A.PrinterAuditID, A.AuditID, A.SerialNr, A.PageCountTotal,a.PageCountColor, A.PageCountMono
    from  InvalidPrinterAudit A
    where A.DeviceID = 90757
) InvalidPrinterAudit on InvalidPrinterAudit.AuditID = Audit.AuditID
```

Comment: That did not do the trick, What Ram posted Above in the comments worked

Comment: Now you mention it, there is the question of why left join on a sub select.